# How to show selected employee details using routing with parameters?

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, angular7

I take an array of employee details and show in it in a table. Using routing with a parameter, I want to show the details of the selected employee

When I click on an employee's details, it shows the selected employee details. However, after that, when I click a to see the details of a second employee, then it still shows the first employee's details.

How can I display the details of the selected employee?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Consider reading this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where's the code you are working with?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: i am working with angular 7

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look here:
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

My bet is you're not subscribing to the change in the route param so when you click the link to update your component is still using the original param.

Observables are just a pain sometimes :(.....